# sql query select combined select from multiple table

Tags: sql, select, string-aggregation

I really don't know what the title should be, but here the question
I have 2 table (actually more)

```
 table a               table b  
id (pk)| country     id(fk)| Branch
------ | ------      ------|--------
01     | Indonesia   01    | Jakarta
                     01    | Bali
```

if i do `select * from a,b where a.id=b.id`
the result will be

```
id | Country  |Branch
01 | Indonesia|Jakarta
01 | Indonesia|Bali
```

I want the result to be like below

```
id | Country   | Branch
01 | Indonesia | Jakarta,Bali
```

Is it possible?
I dont really trying to do research(i mean searching) as I don't know what keyword should I search

Comment: Try looking up GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Thank you @Scovetta pls post as an answer so i can flag answered

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: already solved just need the keyword... im using postgres btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MySQL, [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is the function you're looking for.

Set up the tables like in the request above:

```
create table a (
  `id` int(15) auto_increment primary key,
  `country` varchar(200)
);

create table b (
  `id` int(15) not null,
  `branch` varchar(200),
  foreign key(`id`) references a(`id`)
);

insert into a values (1, 'Indonesia');
insert into b values (1, 'Jakarta');
insert into b values (1, 'Bali');
```

Perform the query:

```
select a.id, 
    a.country, 
    group_concat(distinct b.branch) as 'branch'
from a 
    left join b on a.id=b.id;
```

Output:

```
| id |   country |       branch |
|----|-----------|--------------|
|  1 | Indonesia | Jakarta,Bali |
```